# How to get selected value from jquery selectable widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out how to get data from the selected element once a user selects a box from the widget.

I'm using the selectable widget from jquery:
https://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid

my html:

```
<ol id="Numbers">
            <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
        </ol>
```

I don't understand how to use the selected api at:
https://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected

Tried to use an onclick on the li's but that didn't seem to work:

```
function testvar() {document.getElementByClass('.ui-selected').innerHTML = "CLICKED ME!";
```

}

Comment: I was having trouble understanding the two objects passed to it and how to use them properly. I know the documentation is there but selected wasn't in the link to the event object and the ui link sent me to general information about objects and I didn't know what was in the ui object. Someone else helped me out to understand with some code to look over. Thanks for your helpful tip.

Comment: Thanks your use of  ellipses saved the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you said what you want to do with it:

http://jsfiddle.net/MfegM/2088/

```
$( "#Numbers" ).selectable({
 selected: function( event, ui ) {
 var el = $(ui.selected);
 var num = el.html();
 $('#result').html("You've selected "+num);
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When a user clicked one of the options I wanted it to grab the option they selected and change some inner html based on the number selection. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much help you'll get without more info on what you're trying to accomplish...

```
<head>
  <script>

    $( "#Numbers" ).selectable({
    selected: function( event, ui ) {}
    });

    $( "#Numbers" ).on( "selectableselected", function( event, ui ) {} );

  </script>
</head>
```

Comment: For now I was just trying to understand why both parts of the code are listed on the documentation because I only put $( "#Numbers" ).on( "selectableselected", function( event, ui ) {console.log(ui.selected)} ); without needing to put the first section of code in at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Numbers").on('click', '.ul-state-default ', function(){      
alert($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: Try to find more about delegate() and on() function